# AdMob - "Ad wasn't ready" error with real unit ID (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I try to setup interstitial ads in my app. If I use a test unit ID, ad shows fine, but if I try to use the real unit ID, I see the error "Ad wasn't ready". What I do wrong? Thank for any help!
My code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController {
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    if self.interstitial.isReady {
        self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    } else {
        print("Ad wasn't ready")
    }
   }
}

func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "AdMob Real Unit ID")
    interstitial.delegate = self
    let request = GADRequest()
    GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = ["my device ID from console"]
    interstitial.load(request)
    return interstitial
}
}

extension ViewController: GADInterstitialDelegate {
func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}
}
```

Console:
[image: console]

Answer (score 0):

Launching interstitial ad immediately after page load is disallowed.
Refer Disallowed Interstitial implementation policy https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en

> A common issue is that even though you may intend for the ad to load
> in between page content, the ad itself appears shortly after a new
> page of content has loaded due to carrier latency. To prevent this
> from happening, we recommend you pre-load the interstitial in advance.
> To learn more about how to pre-load your interstitial ad, please
> follow the AdMob Interstitial Ad developer guidelines for apps
> developed for Android and iOS.

Only load the ad on viewDidLoad () https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    let request = GADRequest()
    interstitial.load(request)
  }
}
```

and then Interstitials should be displayed during natural pauses in the flow of an app. Between levels of a game is a good example, or after the user completes a task.

```
@IBAction func doSomething(_ sender: AnyObject) {
  ...
  if interstitial.isReady {
    interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
  } else {
    print("Ad wasn't ready")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think that's the problem. First, when I use the test ID, it works well. Second, I don't display ads immediately after loading the view, I use a delay of 3 seconds, I also tried to use a delay of 30 seconds or more. Third, I've tried showing ads on click of a button, but that didn't fix the problem. I think the problem is with my real unit ID or where or how I define the test device. Have any ideas?

Comment: Is you app live and linked recently? Usually with new apps. it gives a different error code... With button click... can you pull complete stack trace and update in your question

Comment: Yes, I created AdMob acc yesterday. I see the message: "Your account is being verified
This generally takes 24 hours, but in rare cases can take up to two weeks. We'll notify you when verification is complete." Maybe this is a problem?

Comment: I added console message to question

Comment: might be... give it some time and then check... Also donot show ad on viewappear. App id will be blocked as its not allowed implementation policy.

Comment: Ok, I understand, I do it only for test. I'm not sure if I'm using this in the right place?
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = ["******"]

Comment: Solved after app verification!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**
To display your ad units, your AdMob account must be verified.
You must see message in the Google AdMob Console:

```
Your account is approved
Congratulations! We've verified your account information and your ad serving is enabled.
```